# Android AppBar and FAB won't elevate

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am using Android 6.0.1 with support design library 25.1.0. Regardless if I use `app:elevation` or `android:elevation` The AppbarLayout and the FAB won't elevate. The `cardViews` in the same layout do get elevated.

This is the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="255dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/anybody_appbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.anybody.activities.OffersActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">
        <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/offerContent_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="32dp"/>
```

This is how the layout looks:
[image]

The cards are clearly elevated, the FAB however is not even with 32dp elevation.

Comment: As far as I can see, the FAB is elevated.
This is what a non elevated FAB looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb28n.png
Yours is clearly elevated

Comment: If you remove the elevation does it make a difference? Compare them side by side.